# Discretizing lognormal distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

Suppose I have a grid given by

```
import numpy as np
grid = np.linspace(0,20,1000)
```

I want to get a 1000-by-1 vector p so that if one were to plot points 
(grid[i], p[i]) the graph would look like the density of a lognormal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Use scipy's [stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) for obtaining pdf's of probability-distributions!

Numpy, in most (all?) cases only support sampling-methods, not pdf-calculations. What's needed surely depends on the use-case.

Often the pdf plays no role in practical sampling-only implementations, like in this case, where sampling is reduced to [normal-distribution sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution) (often reduced to uniform-sampling combined with other functions) followed by the exponential-function ([code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/bb5d666e84e2eb294543a67c6143d7e9124d1c73/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c#L692)):

```
double rk_lognormal(rk_state *state, double mean, double sigma)
{
    return exp(rk_normal(state, mean, sigma));
}
```

Make sure to read above docs to learn how to use these!

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as spt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rv = spt.lognorm(0.954)  # "frozen" RV (shape-param fixed)
x_points = np.linspace(1,20,1000, dtype=int)  # 0 excluded
plt.scatter(x_points, rv.pdf(x_points))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]